# Dry rub duration

Tags: barbecue

How long is too long to allow for a dry rub with small amounts of salt to sit on a pork shoulder and a brisket. I usually let it sit overnight, but am thinking of extending the time to 24 hours.

Comment: At 24 hours, assuming it is chilled, you will be more than fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twenty four hours will be fine.  Most recipes I see suggest 8 to 24 hours, but if you look around on the BBQ forums, you'll find people who rub and leave in the fridge for up to 3 or 4 days.